# Making CFG and EarleyParser flexible to get same pattern if out of vocabulary word found

Tags: context-free-grammar, earley-parser

I have made a CFG grammar and verifying my grammar using [EarleyParser algorithm](https://github.com/noa/earley-parser).

I wanted to ask how to allow a rule even if something is out of vocabulary from production rules. Let me give a rough example.

```
S1 START I had a burger END
START In the morning
START In the evening
START In the afternoon
END with a coke
END with a pepsi
END with a milk shake
```

Now what I want is if some word is not in the vocabulary of `START` and `END` even then it should be detected. My problem is such that it is not possible to add all the rules in the grammar.

If someone type like this, **In the noon I had a burger with sprite**. Now **In the noon** and **with a sprite** both does not exist in the CFG grammar. Is there any way that for this given input I can still get S1 pattern from EarleyParser.